# How to detect if DWORD is manually defined?

Tags: c++

I have C++ project which uses `DWORD`s. My problem is I don't know how to check whether that `DWORD` is standard Windows `DWORD` type - or user has defined it to something else manually - say `int`.

How can I check this?

The issue is on the target machine where I am interested to check it I can't run Visual Studio. I can only run some .exe file.

On my machine it shows to be `unsigned long` when I use "Go to definition".
How to solve this problem? And check to which type on target machine this DWORD refers to?

Update: It seems it is only important to which type DWORD was defined when project was compiled on some machine - I don't have access to that machine, I only have project source, which likely didn't change.

Answer (score 3):

the `#define` for `DWORD` as `unsigned long` is something compiler check at compile time, when creating a binary executable file.
This binary will be the same on every machine you run it. if compiler decided that it need to allocate 4, 8 or 100 bytes when it has to reserve space for a DWORD, it will allocate same number of bytes on every PC it runs.

Comment: So it is important who compiled it? Then it won't change? I need to check what DWORD is on machine which compiled it?

Comment: yes, you have to be sure that when compiling, the source code has the same #define in all PC where you compile. Which is very likely, if you share a project file with same settings.

Comment: @user200312 DWORD is an alias for type, it is compile time thing, it cannot change at runtime

Comment: @Gian Paolo: I see but only from source can't I check if it is manually defined or not? In case I can't access PC where the project was compiled

Comment: You are actually asking: "did someone (else?)compile the project with different settings?" e.g defining pointer as 64 bit pointers instead of 32bits? "
you should ask to the someone compiling the project in a different PC.... or trust him that it did't sabotate you in a very weird way.

Comment: you can see updated question

Comment: @user200312, please mark the answer as accepted, if you think it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

The question seems silly at first, but it holds some intersting anecodes to it.
many developers come from the managed world into the native and things like "would it matter on different processor/OS" are not clear at first sight.

So, if you're shipping an *Executable*,  it doesn't matter. after compiling the code the code turnes into immutable machine language where `DWORD` stays as it was defined in compile time. if it was `unsigned long` it stays like that on every machine that can run the executable.

But what happens if we're giving a *Library* out? suddenly things *do* matter!
 in this case (which is not yours) you can use `std::is_same`:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<DWORD,unsigned long>::value,"DWORD is not unsigned long, fail to compile");
```

**EDIT:**
add the code line I wrote somewhere in the project source and try to compile it. if it compiles - it probably (just probably) means no-one type-defined it to somehting else.

Comment: My problem is I might not access PC where the project was compiled. I have binary. Now, I do have project and source - can't I see from project source how is DWORD defined?(because I don't want to recompile)

Comment: you can (maybe) reverse-engineer it, but you can't just run a binary and tell it

Comment: Yeah but that I have source doesn't help? Most likely the source contains same definition of DWORD as it was when compiled

Comment: you can look for `typedef DWORD` and such and if you don't find any so the `DWORD` was as the compiler defined it. if it's visual studio so it is `unsigned long`

Comment: Yep that is what I mean so I need to manually search for typedef keyword?

Comment: yes, `typedef`,`#define`,`using` etc

Comment: Typically the definition of DWORD is not in the sourcec ode, but in the windows headers which were installed with visual studio. But there are different ways to use a different definitions of DWORD, for example using `#define`, or modifying the microsoft headers. If the headers were modified, you can only detect that if the program behaves weird at locations where DWORD is used in the source code. You need a debugger or decompiler to spot that. If DWORD is changed in the source code, you can of course check the source. But only if you are sure you have the same exact version of the source code

Comment: @David Haim: I edited question hope now it is clearer

Comment: @Wimmel: Very likely source is same(at least DWORD definition would be same), I was not sure where to look for/how

Comment: " add the code line I wrote somewhere in the project source and try to compile it. if it compiles - it probably (just probably) means no-one type-defined it to somehting else." Yeah but maybe on my PC it refers to unsigned long but on other machine when compiled there are #defines such that it refers to something else?

Comment: but you give a binary, not source code.. decide what are you giving out - a binary or source code?

Comment: @DavidHaim: The binary has already been "given out". So I guess to detect from source code is only way what DWORD is defined to?

Comment: yes, and that returns to what I suggested, adding the line code and trying to compile

Comment: @DavidHaim: Yes but that line doesn't help in case programmer had setup defines such that on the computer where it was compiled DWORD was typedefed to something else, and on my PC it is dypedefed to unsigned long, do you see what I mean? (even if source code didn't change)

Comment: then you can't really know.. but why would someone do it?

Comment: @DavidHaim: I think I still can if source didn't change isn't it? yes someone should not do - check my comments with Paul Mkenzie, especially the project heavily uses Windows API